# Problem with creating ToString() method for the 2 unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-statements, nunit, tostring

I have to create ToString method for two unit test.
My code

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (this.Hours > 9 && this.Minutes > 9)
            {
                return this.Hours + ":" + this.Minutes;
            }
            else if (this.Hours > 9 && this.Minutes < 10)
            {
                return this.Hours + ":" + "0" + this.Minutes;
            }
            else if (this.Hours < 10 && this.Minutes > 9)
            {
                return "0" + this.Hours + ":" + this.Minutes;
            }
            else if (this.Hours < 10 && this.Minutes < 10)
            {
                return "0" + this.Hours + ":" + "0" + this.Minutes;
            }
            else
            {
                return "TimeStruct.Time";
            }
        }
```

These tests in one project prevent me from carrying out this task
Below there are the tests:

```
        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCasesSource), 
          nameof(TestCasesSource.TestCasesForToStringThroughObject))]
        public void ToStringThroughObjectTests(object time)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("TimeStruct.Time", time.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCasesSource), nameof(TestCasesSource.TestCasesForToString))]
        public void ToStringTests(Time time, string str)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(str, time.ToString());
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCasesForToStringThroughObject
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(new Time(24, 0)); //result is TimeStruct.Time
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestCasesForToString
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(new Time(8, 0), "08:00"); //result is 08:00
            }
        }
```

It is the way for creating ToString method such as these two tests will pass in one moment ?
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I would expect `new Time(24, 0)` to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. But anyway...

Comment: What's the problem? What's failing, *exactly*?

Comment: Tell to whoever assigned that homework that desired code is a bad practice and SO folks suggested that you should not do that. Hence you should not turn in that assignment.

Comment: @madreflection I'm pretty sure the name of what is assigned to OP starts with "shad..." - and that is a bad practice, so they should not  turn in that assignment :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I'm not making a connection here. "shad..." what?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say not to turn in the assignment, but it's hard for us to help someone produce something that's objectively bad because of the damage it knowingly causes. My advice is only that one should try not to learn anything from it in the end. To quote Picard, *"There are... 4 lights!!"* ... no matter what the assignment wants you to believe.

Comment: @madreflection "shadowing" (aka `new`) ... Which is what is needed to answer that assignment. Would not envy one who tries to figure out why the code behaves that way in a month :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I'm not sure what shadowing has to do with it. The problem, as I see it, is that can be initialized to an invalid state, and that `ToString` is expected to return the type name in that case (which could've just been a call to `base.ToString()`, but whatever). The constructor arguments should be validated, and this `ToString` implementation can be reduced to `=> $"{Hours:D2}:{Minutes:D2}";` .

Comment: @madreflection hmmm... so you are saying that OP used "access via object" and "access via `Time`" just to confuse readers? (unheard of :) ) Maybe you right - I don't know how NUnit test configured via attributes work and has no interest to figure it now. I thought that `object`/`Time` was important (and *that* is solved by shadowing).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I wasn't paying attention that part. Yeah, the names are terrible. Here's how I read what it's doing:  Test #1: `ToStringThroughObjectTests` is being executed for each value returned by `TestCasesForToStringThroughObject`, which is a single instance with 24 hours and 0 minutes (I figure that's invalid, since we don't have seconds, and therefore no leap seconds). That instance is expected to return the type name; I say that's wrong. The constructor should reject the out-of-range value and this becomes an "expected exception" test case.

Comment: ... Test #2: `ToStringTests` is being executed for each value returned by `TestCasesForToString`, which is a single instance with 8 hours and 0 minutes. I suspect that's passing, but the grammar of the post was not such that it was clear if it was or not.

Comment: Taking `object` rather than `Time` may just be a way to ensure that it's *not* a shadowing implementation and it is in fact calling the correct vtable entry. But then the implementation does what the base-class implementation would *in the invalid state case*, so none of it makes any sense whatsoever.

Comment: Based on @madreflection reading of the requirements `public override string ToString()=> Hours == 24 ? "TimeStruct.Time" : "08:00";` would satisfy both tests. If you really looking for a serious answer review [mre] guidance and sort out if NUnit code is important or some basic Console.WriteLine would explain the problem in less complicated way.

Comment: It is not entirely true what you write. First of all, this is my assignment for my labs in college, hours are calculated modulo by 24, minutes are modulo 60 when their value is greater than the range. For example, if the user specifies 25 as the hour and 15 as the minute, the program must return 25% 24, which is 1, and 15% 60, which is 15, so the result is 01:15. Regarding logic, everything works fine. Hours are created from 0-23. Minutes 0-59 are created. This is my own Time structure. And the problem is, I want all the tests to pass.

Comment: The logical part of my assignment is OK, so don't worry about it. My problem is, with the toString () method, here I just gave some sample values ​​from the tests.

Comment: The solution you provided will not work, because I have a case that the value returned 04:00 for one test in toString () should return 04:00 and TimeStruct.Time for the other. In my opinion, the solution to this problem is somewhere in determining what type is used, whether Time or object, because if it is an object, it has to return this String with the name of namespace and class, and if there is a Time object, it returns the value of the hour in a good format but I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

Comment: It is a way to check in Tostring() If given type in tests is object or string. I know that I should use GetType() or typeof(), but I don't have any idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `ToString` override, you should NOT be getting back `TimeStruct.Time` in your first test - you should be getting back `"00:00"`. I'm guessing that for this assignment you are supposed to *hide* `ToString` rather than *override* it so that you can see that the `object` version is called in the first test, and the `Time` version in the second. You *could* do that by making `ToString` a `new` method instead of an `override`.  While that's generally not a good practice, if this is a learning exercise to understand the difference between hiding and overriding methods, it is a reasonable test.

But, since this is a school assignment, you should *ask your professor*. I'm just guessing based on the expected results.

Comment: Thank you very much D Stanley. Deleting override from definition of ToString method solved my problem.

Comment: Great - do you understand _why_? I get the feeling that's the point of the assignment.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I think that was a way to show difference between hiding and overriding, when method is hiding, then it is possibility to check the type of the class and the value. With overriding method that was impossible because during overriding it is possibility to check the value. Perhaps I can't explain this in good way, but I understand how that is work and why.